# Sum of sub query result with group by laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables one `transactions` and another `transaction_charges` each transaction might have multiple transaction charges means an has many relationships. now what I need is to get transactions that occured in a month/year/week. it would be better if I can do a `group by` inside the query itself rather than doing a loop with the model collections.

so far I have written code to fetch the transactions with its total charge

```
 $defaults = collect([]);
    /** @var Builder $transactions */
    $transactions = app(TransactionServices::class)
        ->getTransactions($defaults->merge($options))
        ->has('charges')->has('operation')->selectSub(function ($query){
            /** @var Builder $query */
            $query->selectRaw('SUM(amount)')->from('transaction_charges tc')
                ->whereRaw('tc.transaction_id = transaction.transaction_id');
        }, 'totalCharge');
```

but to get the monthly result I need to do a group by but I don't think the group by will fetch correct aggregated result from the subquery as here what I need is the sum of the `totalCharge` in a month/week/group. so how I can get the transactions with its charges sum up to the monthly/Yearly group

Comment: Just write a raw query. Use `hydrateRaw()` if you need the result as eloquent collection.

Comment: It would help if you add your tables/models structure and explain your use case.

Comment: there are two tables `transactions` and `transaction_charges` and there is a `has many` relation between `transactions` and `transaction_charges`. what I need is to get a collection of `transactions` models grouped by 'month/year/day'' with extra model attributes which represent the sum of total transaction charges of that group for the related transactions

Comment: @PaulSpiegel actually not getting a raw query solution too for above situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well how your system works but I did an intent of understand it and think one possible solution for your problem.
I made my best effort to explain the code. I Hope you understand that english is not my native language.

```
// I suppose that TransactionServices represents "transaction" Table and has transaction_charges
$transactions = TransactionServices::has('charges')->get(); // If I understand well your code that returns the transactions that has charges.
// $transactions = TransactionServices::has('charges')->has('operation')->get(); // that returns the transactions that has charges AND operation.

// the month to filter the charges
$month = 'march'; // selected month can be dynamic this is an example

// Get all TransactionServices with total amount of charges
$transactionsWithTotalCharge = $transactions->each(function ($transaction, $key) {
    $totalAmount = $transaction->charges->where('month', $month)->sum('amount'); // This make the sum of all charges of march for that transaction 
    $transaction->put('chargesTotalAmount' , $totalAmount); // This add chargesTotalAmount to every TransactionServices
    return $transaction;
});

// You can verify if the sum is correct
foreach($transactionsWithTotalCharge as $transaction) {
    // dd($transaction); 
    dd($transaction->chargesTotalAmount); 
}
```

I could not test that and hope that work

Comment: actually here you made yourself a loop after queried all possible results without applying the groupBy inside the query itself. what I need is to apply the groupBy inside the query itself and then return the transaction record with a sum of charges of a specific month/week/year

Comment: You need to group `TransactionServices` or `charges`?
Here I Obtain all `TransactionServices` that has `charges` and then I filter for each `TransactionServices` the `charges` where match with an specific month and make the sum for all them

Comment: when I do `->where('month', $month)` you can use `whereBetween`

Comment: there are two tables `transactions` and `transaction_charges` and there is a `has many` relation between `transactions` and `transaction_charges`. what I need is to get a collection of `transactions` models grouped by 'month/year/day'' with extra model attributes which represent the sum of total transaction charges of that group for the related transactions

Comment: when added the `->get()` we got the queried result collection without any 'group by' filters what I need is to apply the group by inside the query